# Python get text from <a> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a list of web-pages that I'm looping through. My goal is to get text from each of these web-pages IF there is something. I'm looking for certain -tag elements that have same className. First part (looping) is working perfectly but for some reason i'm getting only value [None] while printing this -tags text.

here is what i'm doing:

```
jotain = []
col = 3
for row, urls in enumerate(links):
    page = requests.get(urls)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    sposti = soup.find('a', {'class' : '_contactLink_1i8pl_1'})
    jotain.append(sposti)
    print(jotain.text)

sheet.write(row, col, sposti)
```

It returns me: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'"

And this is how the html looks like:

```
<a class="_contactLink_1i8pl_1" href="mailto:info@talligym.fi">info@talligym.fi</a>
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jotain is a list that is holding your attribute elements, try

```
jotain.append(sposti.text)
print(jotain)
```

Edit: Check whether you are indeed getting the data first by printing the variable 'sposti' just to debug.

Comment: This gives me the same error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: AAANNDD we have an new error: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the data? Have you tried printing 'sposti' just to debug?

Comment: Yeah actually that seems to be the problem! Thanks for help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You're appending the data found in `soup` to a list `jotain`, you don't need to call `jotain.text` on the list, this is what you would do to read the text found in `soup`. You would need to append the text part from `soup` to `jotain`;

```
jotain.append(sposti.text)
```

Just call `print(jotain)` and it will return what you need.

EDIT: You might also want to use `soup.findall` if you have more than one matching tag, otherwise it will only return the first found value.

Comment: for soem reason i get only value: [None] even though there is some text on some pages

Comment: @naample You would need to append the text part from soup to jotain `jotain.append(sposti.text)`

Answer (score 1):

You have appended tags to list and trying to get text from that list. That's why the error has been thrown. Try this.

```
jotain.append(sposti.text)
print(jotain)
```

You can try list comprehension also.

```
jotain.append(sposti)
jotain = [i.text for i in jotain]
print(jotain)
```

Hope this gives clarity! Cheers!